# Sending emails automatically in Android but using my company server and not Gmail servers

Tags: android, email, background, smtp

I am trying to send an email in the background from my android app and I am using the JavaMail for this. I have included the three Jar files, have the JSSEProvider Class and the Mail class. All of it works perfectly fine with Gmail but as soon as change the host to my company server and the email id to our Microsoft exchange email ids (our company emails ids), it doesn't send a mail. Nor does it give any error. It says email sent but I get no mail.

I followed this link: http://gafurbabu.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/sending-email-in-android-via-smtp-without-using-the-default-android-appbuiltin-email-application/

My company server does not require any login credentials so I created a new constructor as follows:

```
public GMailSender(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "abcd.companyName.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        session = Session.getInstance(properties, this);
        }
```

And in the Main activity I have called it as:

```
GMailSender sender = new GMailSender();
sender.sendMail("subject!!","body@@","employee@company.com","employee1@company.com");
```

The send function in GMailSender class goes as follows:

```
public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
try{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject(subject);   
    message.setDataHandler(handler);   
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
    Transport.send(message);   
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
}
```

How can I make it work for my company server? Is there any different way to do it for the Microsoft Exchange account?